# Загрузка файлов в Django 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Подскажите, как правильно загрузить файл в Django. Делаю следующее:

```
# In forms.py...
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.ImageField()


#urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('upload/', views.UploadPageView.as_view(), name='upload')
]


#views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .forms import UploadFileForm

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class UploadPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'


def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        save_path = 'media/images/' # папка для сохранения файлов
        if form.is_valid():
            # сохранение файла
            with open(save_path+request.FILES['file'].name, 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in request.FILES['file'].chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('home')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response(request, "upload.html", {'form': form})


# upload.html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input class="btn-get-started scrollto" type="file" value="Upload file" />
<button class="btn-get-started scrollto" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Загружаю файл, нажимаю upload и переход на пустую страницу, а в консоли

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /upload/
Method Not Allowed: /upload/
```

Comment: Я не понимаю, к чему относится метод upload. Это отдельная вьюха или часть UploadPageView? И как она используется?

Comment: @Александр Кажется тут я и запнулся. Как сделать метод upload частью UploadPageView, чтобы весь этот код работал.

Comment: надо переопределить метод post для UploadPageView, в ней должен быть весь код upload

Comment: не совсем понимаю как это сделать в коде. Если не сложно, подскажите.

Comment: @Andrey Перенесите в класс `UploadPageView` метод `upload` и переименуйте его в `post`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете CBV для своего проекта, а метод upload сделан в FBV. На мой взгляд, для начинающих FBV более понятен: если вы укажете на upload в url, то получите желаемый результат:

```
path('upload/', views.upload, name='upload')
```

Если же вы хотите попробовать CBV, то ваш код должен выглядеть подобно этому:

```
class UploadPageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'upload.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        save_path = 'media/images/' # папка для сохранения файлов
        if form.is_valid():
            # сохранение файла
            with open(save_path+request.FILES['file'].name, 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in request.FILES['file'].chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('home')

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return self.render_to_response({'form': form}, **kwargs)
```

Так же хочу обратить ваше внимание, что папка `media/images/`, в которую вы ведете запись, должна быть доступна для записи

Удачи